# Is there a way to fine tune a kinect?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect

I just purchased a Kinect for the Xbox360. It is a bit over sensitive.  I currently have the 6 required feet. I want to know if there is a way to 'fine tune' or correct the sensitivity of my movements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean how to `calibrate` the Kinect, then here is the [website](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/kinect/body-tracking/start-calibration) describing the process.

Comment: I will check it out soon.